# How to install and run qt-designer for python

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm new to ubuntu, I entered the following commands
`sudo apt-get install python-pyqt` and `sudo apt-get install qt-designer`.
Both the commands executed successfuly but I'm not able to figure out how to launch the `qt-designer` program.

Comment: Please see my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419138/is-qt-designer-bundled-with-anaconda/58365150#58365150 Thank you, Mehi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

with `sudo apt-get install python-qt4 qt4-designer` should work.

You can find it if you search it with `apt-cache search qt | grep designer`:

```
libqt4-designer - Qt 4 designer module
libqt4-designer-dbg - Qt 4 designer library debugging symbols
qt4-designer - graphical designer for Qt 4 applications
kdesignerplugin - Integration of KF5 widgets in Qt Designer/Creator
kdesignerplugin-data - Integration of KF5 widgets in Qt Designer/Creator
kgendesignerplugin - Integration of KF5 widgets in Qt Designer/Creator
libopenrpt-dev - graphical SQL report writer, designer and rendering engine (development)
libopenrpt1v5 - graphical SQL report writer, designer and rendering library
libqscintilla2-designer - Qt4 Designer plugin for QScintilla 2
libqscintilla2-designer-dbg - Qt4 Designer plugin for QScintilla 2 (debug)
libqt5designer5 - Qt 5 designer module
libqt5designercomponents5 - Qt 5 Designer components module
libqt5scintilla2-designer - Qt5 Designer plugin for QScintilla 2
libqt5scintilla2-designer-dbg - Qt5 Designer plugin for QScintilla 2 (debug)
libqxt-designer0 - LibQxt extensions to Qt Designer
openrpt - graphical SQL report writer, designer and rendering engine
```

And search more info about the package with `apt-cache show qt4-designer`.

Answer (score 18):

Considering the packages names did *dramatically* change, the procedure with Ubuntu 20.04 is now:

```sh
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev
```

Then, Qt Designer is installed as `designer`, and is also in the start menu.

[Credits](https://pythonbasics.org/qt-designer-python/)
| [Manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html)

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

type on your Terminal

```
designer-qt4
```

or if /usr/bin isn't included in your PATH:

```
/usr/bin/designer-qt4
```

Answer (score 0):

To search for available packages run:

```
apt-cache search qt*designer
```

Which will output:

```
libqt4-designer - Qt 4 designer module
libqt5designer5 - Qt 5 designer module
python-pyqt5 - Python 2 bindings for Qt5
python3-pyqt5 - Python 3 bindings for Qt5
```

Then install the packages you need:

```
sudo apt install libqt5designer5 python3-pyqt5
```