# How to run Qt Designer in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am teaching myself PyQt6 using [this tutorial](https://www.pythonguis.com/installation/install-qt-designer-standalone/). I get the examples running and I want to use Qt Designer. I can install it but in all cases (mentioned below) Qt designer starts and hangs. I have to `kill -9` in order to stop the job. The things I have done are:

- using the link above, it asks you to `pip install pyqt6-tools`. When calling `pyqt6-tools designer` Qt designer starts and hangs
- I tried [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763877/how-to-install-and-run-qt-designer-for-python) with the same results (starts and hangs):

```
    sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
    sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev
```

- I tried to `apt install sudo apt install designer-qt6` but the resulted in `sudo apt install designer-qt6 not found` when I tried to start it

Anybody any idea how to install and start a running version PyQt6 designer? Preferably stand alone but other solkutions are welcome as well.

Comment: I am using Kubuntu 22.04 and synaptic shows designer-qt6 and clicking on it adds a lot of additional files. I still and on 5 for my one app, and will need to convert soon, so cannot otherwise help. `sudo apt install synaptic`.

Comment: Installing it by synaptic didn't help.After installating the system cannot find any package wiith the name designer-qt6. What exactly is installed with designer-qt6?

Comment: Many apps install under one name but the name used to launch it is different. It should have a gui entry.